# Java ExecutorService ShutdownNow Takes Ages

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I have a Java ExecutorService (Fixed Thread Pool of 1) that I pass runnable tasks into for future execution. Each task is normally completed within 10 seconds. The ExecutorService simply works it way through the tasks. If I shutdown my application I run the following;

```
if (taskProcessor != null) {
    taskProcessor.shutdownNow();
    while (!taskProcessor.isTerminated()) {
        // Wait For All Submitted Tasks To Finish
    }
}
```

The problem is it seems to takes an age for it to shutdown, sometimes it may take a few minutes, sometimes it never seems to shutdown and sometimes it shutdowns in seconds! There could potentially be upto around 2000 tasks at any time within the executor queue but I simply would like it finish it's current task being performed and quit. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Busy waiting is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You did not follow right sequence to shutdown `ExecutorService`.

You have to call `shutdown`, `shutdownNow` and `awaitTermination` in a specific order as recommended by [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

```
void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the tasks being executed. ThreadPoolExecutor will not end till all tasks end. shutdownNow() interrupts all tasks but tasks may ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, I shall add some debugging and try to explore if this is what is happening. I have a timer attached to each task to monitor task timeouts so wondering if this is where the problem is occurring and running task is ignoring the interrupt because of the timer.

Comment: note that a task can only react to interrupts if it is designed for that

Comment: I think that is the issue. I'm just adding a catch InterruptedException and wrapping the task with a while loop. Hopefully my debug will shed some further light in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do better by not having your code doing busy waiting. That will free a CPU to get the tasks finished. And prevent contention for any lock used by isTerminated.